# An application can make up to 5,000 userless requests per hour

Tags: foursquare

does it mean 5000 per clientid per hour OR per IP per hour?

Comment: the docs says per application. Which is in my defintion not a clientid and not an IP address. Maybe you need to elaborate on your defintion of clientid and IP. And why do you ask this (in other words, what is your (expected) problem)

Comment: i'm developing an ios app, i want to know if the docs means that an app with the same clientid can only request 5000 times per hour? isn't it too small?

Comment: It is too small if the app you are developing is generating more requests then the rate limit alows. Based on the info you provided so far there is no way to answer your question.

Comment: assume i have 5000 user for my ios app ,does it mean if everyone does a useless request, for this hour my app can't make any useless request?if i have 5001 user, the last one can't make useless request?

Comment: Yes, that is what I expect to happen. Don't do any useless requests in that case, only usefull....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not per IP! You can check that yourself

From a terminal:

```
curl -i https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74\&client_id=   <client_id_1>\&client_secret=<client_secret_1>\&v=<YYYYMMDD>
```

and then use another client_id/secret from the same machine (same IP):

```
curl -i https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74\&client_id=<client_id_2>\&client_secret=<client_secret_2>\&v=<YYYYMMDD>
```

Now look at the X-RateLimit-Limit and X-RateLimit-Remaining in both headers and you can see that they are not sharing the same limit!

Comment: thanks for answer my question,you are right,i have emailed to FoursSquare and they told me it's per clientID,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this means that each application clientId can make 5,000 userless requests per hour. If you need more requests per hour, see Foursquare's [rate limit guidelines](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/ratelimits).